# "Can't you see the person is embroidering?" - idiomaticity and alternatives?

Tags: idioms, expression-choice

Two persons, who were not privy to a scene, are now observing two others who are talking:

> [...]
>
> [one of the former, reacting to something that was just said]
>
> -Why did she/he say that!? What is he/she talking about??
>
> -Can't you see the person **is embroidering**?
>
> -Oh, I see... [or]
> -Where's the needle?? [or]
> -*Android*-a-ring?? [!]

Is that idiomatical in [AmE](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/embroider)/[BrE](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/embroider) today? Is there another expression in context for saying that someone is making up details, or even embellishing a story - yet not necessarily lying - **and** which is related to some *fine craft* or *technique*(science, business etc.), while possibly being more idiomatic than [*to embroider*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=embroider)([NED](https://archive.org/stream/oed03arch#page/n870/mode/1up))?<sup>1</sup> I'm looking at the description of the [*make up*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/make%20up) verb phrase but don't find it particularly insightful...

---

<sub>1. The archaic verb [*to broider*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/broider) is obviously very similar to the french verb [*broder*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/broder), which also has that decorative needlework meaning(and the verb could mean *upon something* as well as *the making up* of the whole garment), but also figuratively speaking, with words or even music, bears this idea(also referenced in the NED) of an industrious and pretty *make up* basically, while being completely idiomatic: when you think about what *dentelle*(lace) is for instance, it's about a clever, custom (hand, preferably)made, and sophisticated pattern(of cloth). Therein lies the idea imho.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Gilding the lily**" is a good expression for inappropriate adornment; when used of a narrative account, it implies departure from strict historical accuracy.

Comment: Thanks! this is beautiful. I wish it didn't have that wasteful/unnecessary connotation but still.

Answer (score 1):

One might say they are "embellishing" a story. (Or, "exaggerating", although that suggests stretching the truth, rather than adorning it.)

Comment: Thank you. But please note I have _embellishing_ directly in the Q text. Also, perhaps I should have said "is a craft" instead of craft "related". What I mean is that _embroidering_ is literally this craft, it could be a profession. I'm looking for that component too...

Comment: There is a technique in art called "collage", which involved adding layers to build a textured picture. In sewing, adding layers to build up a decorative pattern is called "appliqué. Either of these craft methods could be a metaphor for embellishing a story.